# Pass formula into function / list comprehension as argument

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension that sums together values calculated in a list

```
sum([((x*y)*z) for ((x, y), z) in [(element["size"], element["quantity"]) for element in lst]])
```

but would like to have the function I have written to be more generic so I can pass the calculation, format and variables in so that the function would read:

```
sum([calculation for format in [variables for element in lst]])
```

how do I pass in the calculation and format as variables into the function? Can this be done?

```
calculation = ((x*y)*z)
format = ((x, y), z)
```

Comment: A function can be an argument, but your syntax doesn't make sense. You can read up on definition functions here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Comment: To add on to what @jonrsharpe said, split up your code a little bit more, especially when you’re debugging.

Answer (score 1):

you have to actually define your function properly, then you can use it in the list comprehension, for example:

```
def calculation(x,y,z):
    return (x*y)*z
```

now the function is defined and you can use it in the list comprehension:

```
sum([calculation(x,y,z) for ((x, y), z) in [(element["size"], element["quantity"]) for element in lst]])
```

as mentioned in the comments,  I suggest reading up on how to use functions in python:

[functions in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

the same kind of idea can be applied to any part of the list comprehension you are trying to simplify